# Android Studio 0.4 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After I have updated my Studio from 0.3.7 to 0.4.0, I can't compile my project. I found a solution on stackoverflow: [Duplicate files copied (Android Studio 0.4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0)

I updated my project to gradle 0.7.+, but I don't know where I must put the next strings:

```
android {

    packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

My logcat: log

```
Execution failed for task ':Prog:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: /home/scijoker/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgProject/Prog/libs/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
    File 2: /home/scijoker/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgProject/Prog/libs/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
```

P.S. Develop in ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Inside `android` section

Comment: Thanks. I put block packagingOptions() in main gradle conf file. First I inserted this block in libraries gradle files. All work's perfectly=)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Putting the dependecies at the top and the packageOptions at the end worked for me.

```
apply plugin: 'android'.
```

Here is my full build.gradle at the app folder.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 10
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

EDIT: Almost all OS licence include the obligation to "include a copy of the licence" into your project. So this means, that you have to include a copy of all OS licences you use into you projects. By "excluding" them in gradle, you violate the licences.

Excluding them from the project might not be the best option.
Thank you R.S. for the info.

Comment: This one seems to work for me as well. What is all these exclude directives, by the way? Why do we need this?

Comment: @Andree The reason we exclude the files is because we do not want the .txt (and other) files to be included in the .apk that will be generated by the build.

Comment: exclude is not recognized outside of android{} :/

Comment: For me it is worked with adding exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' and exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'.

Comment: packagingOptions must be within android

Comment: Exclude should be inside android { }, then only it works.

Comment: ! This Solution violates all Open source licences !
As you are obliged to add the original licence text of each library to your package

Comment: @R.S I don't really understand which open source licence you are mentioning. Please give me detail so I can modify it.

Comment: Hi. Any. Almost all OS licence include the obligation to "include a copy of the licence" into your project. So this means, that you have to include a copy of all OS licences you use into you projects. By "excluding" them in gradle, you violate the licences.

Comment: for most licences you need to include license.txt if you are distributing their source codes or module. When compiling the APK no source code is being distributed, executable is being distributed. So it's fine to include it in this case.

Comment: R.S, you are aware that the convention on Android is to just have an activity in your app that displays all of the libraries you use and their respective licenses, yes? No license literally says you have to include it as a .txt file, and in fact including it in your APK would accomplish absolutely nothing.

Comment: The `packagingOptions` must be in the `android` object.

Comment: use `pickFirst` instead of `exclude` to prevent losing the licenses

Answer (score 51):

Attention!! Possible OpenSource license violation.

With excluding license.txt files as proposed above you may violate some opensource licenses as it is a common point in opensource licences to agree to add it to your source.
Better check your opensource licences.

**Update:**
Until there is a better solution, use

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

like this you at least fulfill a part of the license obligation

**You also can try:**

```
packagingOptions {
   merge 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 23):

just add

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

in build.gradle

Comment: Our are violating opensource licence like this

Answer (score 16):

You can fix it by adding the following code to `project/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // Fixed build error : Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/xxx
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This problem was fixed 1.5 years ago
Thanks for answer

Comment: :-) I just met this problem today and found this thread. And I don't notice the date.

Comment: You didn't notice the date AND ignored all the other answers.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same problem as per new version of gradle, Below **build.gradle** text format work for me :

There are two jackson jars in my libs folder.

```
android {
         compileSdkVersion 21
         buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

         defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.omtlab.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
         }
         buildTypes {
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
         }
         packagingOptions {
            exclude 'libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar'
            exclude 'libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
         }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against this for ~5 hours today. :) It's the `packagingOptions { exclude 'libs/jackson...' }` that fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Adding:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

worked for me, biniam_Ethiopia's solution is probably the most fail-safe

Answer (score 8):

While inserting this code

```
android{

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
 }
}
```

***MAKE SURE*** if in **error** it is showing

> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/**LICENSE.txt**

then add

```
 android{

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
 }

}
```

if in **error** it is showing

> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/**LICENSE**

then add

```
 android{

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
 }

}
```

if in **error** it is showing

> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/**license.txt**

then add

```
 android{

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
 }

}
```

In short text CASE and document FORMAT(.txt) is so important.

(this error exist in Android Studio 1.1.0 also)

Answer (score 6):

This will help you solve the problem

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```

Comment: why this has so many downvotes if is basically the same as the proper answer  ?

Answer (score 4):

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

**Add in build.gradle file and syn project**

Answer (score 3):

I just add 2:

```
android{

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
 }

}
```

Comment: Will this be included still, in app production?

Answer (score 3):

This may very well be bad practice, however if you are including multiple large libraries, you may find yourself working through hundreds of these kinds of conflicts.

Listed below is a super-simple fix for such cases:

```
android { 
    ....
    packagingOptions {
        // Allow the compilation process to choose the dependencies for us.
        pickFirst "**"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and solved it without the `packingOptions()` and `exclude` function.  I was adding two dependencies but one was a sub-group of the first.  This caused the error, once I removed one of them I got a clean build.  I recommend checking for a similar error within your dependency block.

Comment: Hi, i'm solved this problem a long time ago by adding packingOptions() . Thanks for answer) +1

Comment: This problem is fixed in new available version of AS

Answer (score 2):

When using `java-jwt` and `jackson-core` together use following:

```
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/pom.properties")
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/pom.xml")
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.properties")
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.xml")
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.properties")
exclude("META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml")
```