# Gradle and Android Studio Duplicate File Copied from same jar

Tags: java, android, dependencies, gradle, android-studio

When trying to include EasyMock in my Android project, I get the following error when running my tests.  Which is trying to package up the same jar twice.

```
Execution failed for task ':Example:packageDebugTest'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST
    File 1: /home/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.easymock/easymock/3.2/c82f7fa3ef377d8954b1db25123944b5af2ba4/easymock-3.2.jar
    File 2: /home/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.easymock/easymock/3.2/c82f7fa3ef377d8954b1db25123944b5af2ba4/easymock-3.2.jar
```

My build.gradle looks like:

```
android {
...
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:3.8.2+'
    instrumentTestCompile('org.easymock:easymock:3.2'){
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
}
```

And I don't feel it is a good idea to exclude `INDEX.LIST`  I guess even if I did that, I'd get duplicates for every file in the jar.

Why is it trying to add `EasyMock` twice? How can I stop it from doing this?

NB - Android environments:

- `Android-Studio` version 0.4.0
- `Android Gradle Plugin` version 0.7.1
- `Gradle` version 1.9

Comment: It's weird that it adds easyMock twice. I'll look into it. I created a bug to track this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64279

Comment: While solving such error always take care of what told in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30935051/4773561 !!!

Comment: While solving such error always take care of what told in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30935051/4773561 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around I did the following, which gets my tests to build

Manually add:

- cglib-nodeps-2.2.2.jar
- dexmaker-1.0.jar
- dexmaker-dx-1.0.jar
- easymock-3.2.jar
- junit-3.8.2.jar

to `test_libs` dir,

and add the following to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
    instrumentTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'test_libs', include: '*.jar')
...
}
```

Everything compiles fine and the tests run:

I also had to do the following: [dexmaker-issue2](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=2#c6) to fix the no dex cache issue.

Comment: I think instrumentTestCompile may have been renamed to androidTestCompile