# How do I find out a gradle task's actions and configurations that are composing it

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to investigate what kind of actions(instructions) + configurations are composing a specific gradle task(intention is to reverse-engineer it and rewrite it).

In my case this is the task that I want to do reverse-engineering on(from an android build):

> :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease

Which will help furthermore to investigate this issue: 
[How do I resolve "Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923461/how-do-i-resolve-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf)