# Exclude dependency library assets from jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Im working on a library A, which has dependency on library B(jar lib) in gradle file:

```
compile files('libs/B.jar')
```

Library B has assets inside like pictures, dex files etc. 
When i build library A, i see exactly the same assets inside it. Problem is that i don't want to have duplicated assets inside A. This cause following error when building apk, which has dependency on both libs A and B:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK assets/dex/d.dex
>       File1: Documents/projects/TestProjects/SampleApp/app/libs/B.jar
>       File2: Documents/projects/TestProjects/SampleApp/app/libs/A.jar

How can i exclude assets from A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/\*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923461/how-do-i-resolve-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf)