# Android Gradle Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/license.txt

Tags: android, gradle, spring-android

I'm going to add RESTful Web Service support with Spring to my Android application as described here https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/.

This is top-level build.gradle config:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my `app/build.gradle` config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    }

}
```

Right now it fails with a following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/license.txt
    File1: user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.android\spring-android-rest-template\1.0.1.RELEASE\e132d929bd181941f79b0d63edafb8a86ae6fd33\spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
    File2: user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.android\spring-android-core\1.0.1.RELEASE\e68f0e8e4b636ee30c4de58953be38d9b72a5e3b\spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/\*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923461/how-do-i-resolve-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Write below lines in your app level gradle file

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with these lines.. For a some reason it doesn't help

Comment: Ok.. Good to know :)

Comment: OMG how people leaved without Stackoverflow? It would take ages to find this solution. Thank you stranger

Comment: Will anyone explain what those lines do briefly please

Comment: Spent two hours trying to getting my tests working on my android project.

Comment: It doesn't remove "duplicate" files. It excludes the listed files without any further checks. In most cases this "solution" is illegal.

Comment: God Sets Up Your Work... ;-)

Comment: @TheincredibleJan do you have any legal suggestions? As I have been searching for hours but couldn't find any solution

Comment: With this solution you violate the licence rules. Check my answer above.

Comment: In my case, I added exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0' also along with the above set. Then it worked.

Answer (score 11):

If the solution in the selected answer does not fix your problem, try adding

```
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
```

as well. Or basically, identify the name of the duplicate file and exclude it. The addition above fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Its helps me. Try this code:)**

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding these lines helped me.

```
shadowJar {
    // Filtering shadow jar contents by file pattern.
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/attribute/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/attributegroup/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/element/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/identityconstraint/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/javaname/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/modelgroup/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/namespace/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/src/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/sXML*/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/system/s8C3F193EE11A2F798ACF65489B9E6078/**'
    exclude 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/type/**'

    exclude 'repackage/**'

    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/**'

    // these are only needed when handling Visio files, remove it if you would like to use Visio support
    dependencies {
        exclude(dependency('com.github.virtuald:curvesapi'))
        exclude(dependency('commons-codec:commons-codec'))
    }

    // Relocate javax dependencies so Android does not choke
    relocate 'javax.xml.namespace', 'org.apache.poi.javax.xml.namespace'
    relocate 'javax.xml.stream', 'org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream'
    relocate 'javax.xml.XMLConstants', 'org.apache.poi.javax.xml.XMLConstants'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    exclude 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'classworlds'
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-model'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-project'
    all*.exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    all*.exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    all*.exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    all*.exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    all*.exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    all*.exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    all*.exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
packagingOptions {
   merge'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

or if they are the same

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```