# Why do I get this error when I add the Google Translate client library to my Android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-translate

I'm trying to add the Google Translate client library to my Android project per [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#java-install), which tells me to add this line to my dependencies in build.gradle of my *library* project (which is a dependency of my app project):

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-translate', version: '0.4.0'
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':typeSmart:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\Barry\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.auto.value\auto-value\1.1\f6951c141ea3e89c0f8b01da16834880a1ebf162\auto-value-1.1.jar
    File2: C:\Users\Barry\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.11\e32303ef8bd18a5c9272780d49b81c95e05ddf43\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
    File3: C:\Users\Barry\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.inject\guice\4.0\f990a43d3725781b6db7cd0acf0a8b62dfd1649\guice-4.0.jar
```

I understand what the error means technically but not why it appears in this case. I tried to suppress it by adding a `packagingOptions` block to my build.gradle per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586800/android-gradle-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt) (and others), but it didn't help (plus it's illegal).

It seems unlikely that Google would publish an API with internal inconsistencies. The problem may be specific to my environment. My app consists of a library module that contains most of my code. It's a dependency of the app module. I suspect that has something to do with it.

I'm using: Gradle 2.14.1; Android Studio 2.2.2; Build tools 25.0.0.

Have you successfully added the Google Translate client library to your Android project? If so, how?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried to clean project, clear cache, and rebuild ?

Comment: I did a clean build from AS and I ran gradlew clean. I also blew away ~/.gradle.

Comment: 2 points, first i think the isue is because 2 lib are by google, and thus license is duplicate issue somehow? 2nd in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt it talks about `Putting the dependecies at the top and the packageOptions at the end`, not sure though, it worth a try?

Comment: It may be a bug in Android Studio or Gradle: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1319

Comment: Yep it's a bug: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1361

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-translate</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev47-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {

    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-translate:v2-rev47-1.22.0'

}
```

And checkout this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translating-text-with-rest

and in github: 
https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

Hope it will be help you otherwise you can knock me for furthe help.

Comment: I don't have a pom.xml file.

Comment: please check this link : https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

Comment: @BarryFruitman do you get warnings/errors when you build with this solution? I get BULD SUCCESSFUL: but their is 8 warnings/336 errors lol. Nice job Google

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug on Google's end: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1361

I'll leave the bounty open in case someone wants to offer a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the following a try, insert in your android block:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'

    // `return void` removes the lint error: `Not all execution paths return a value`.
    return void
}
```

Add any additional files that are duplicated across library projects and your own.
When it comes time to give credit, merge all of the above into their own html page (or a text file) for presentation.

Comment: I already described this solution in my original post. It didn't work then either.