# Cannot built project because of Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF, can i exclude a particular jar from built apk to avoid the issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForLocalDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>       File1: /home/solulab/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j-dom/0.7.2/1c289aa264548a0a1f1b43685a9cb2ab23f67287/apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar
>       File2: /home/solulab/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7.2/a81264fe0265ebe8fd1d8128aad06dc320de6eef/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar

Comment: try to exclude that jar

Comment: @Madhur i tried that but then app crashes on startup, seems it also excludes some other imp stuff, so can you please help me with the exclude statement for these particular jars

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923461/how-do-i-resolve-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0

Comment: @Madhur thanks for the time, yes i have tried all of them, the thing here is that i cant just add exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' as it will exclude all the dependencies, which breaks the apk, i am looking for a statement which will only exclude this :apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar  or/and  apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar, so thats where I am stuck

Comment: Try to add `packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }` in your build.gradle

Comment: compile project (':projectname') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.james'
    }

Comment: one more solution:
`sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/ourcompany/someotherpackage/polling/**'
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?