# Error:Execution failed for task ':

Tags: android, json, firebase

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>
> File1: C:\Users\SHASHI.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
>
> File2: C:\Users\SHASHI.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
>
> File3: C:\Users\SHASHI.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar

Comment: please provide your build.gradle

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I've only seen this with older versions (2.x) of the Firebase SDK. If that is what you're using, see this for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607609/issue-while-gradle-build-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license