# Gradle sync Error in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a project for a client. The project seems to work fine in the old Android Studio, but ever since I updated my studio to 2.2.2, I am getting the sync error when trying to run the app, the error message is as posted below.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
         File1: /home/empressum/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5.1/eecbb0b998e77629862a13d957d552b3be58fc4e/httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
         File2: /home/empressum/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3/5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7/httpmime-4.3.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923461/how-do-i-resolve-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf

Answer (score 0):

Add following into respective build.gradle file

```
  android {
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
}
```

Comment: Where do i put these lines, In the app gradle file or the project gradle file?

Comment: Put it inside android tag of build.gradle.(Eda gradle inte akath ulla android tag il id.

Comment: There are two build.gradle files, one in the project folder and another in the app folder, in which one should I put??.(Onne maryadekke paranje thaadey)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check if you have 2 references of the same library or .jar included and remove the duplicate reference.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are using dependency which is conflicting with androids supplied jars. Add

> compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
>
> ```
>    exclude module: 'httpclient'
>    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
> ```
>
> }

in your gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two many libraries files for http call instead use jar file on libs or add some dependency in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

The error went when I downloaded the project zip file again and run it. But this time when Android Studio asked me to update the gradle file, I denied. I dont know if this explains the error, but now the project is running fine on any device I connect.