# Duplicate Files copied in APK META-INF when Gradle building

Tags: android, gradle

I've been looking around at [some of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt) posted here about this error but have had no luck.  I'm hoping to get some clarification about what's going on. my error is as follows:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml
>       File1: /home/colin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2/b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
>       File2: /home/colin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5/commons-io-1.3.2.jar

I've done

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

in the `app > build.gradle` file, but the problem persists.  Is there somewhere else I should put this, or perhaps just delete some file?  Or perhaps I've excluded too many files - Should I omit some of these lines, and if so which ones?  I also tried moving the dependencies in to the top, above `Android` to no avail.

Furthermore I'm a little confused about some of the advice given in these posts.  What is the operating difference between `Exclude` and `PickFirst`?   They seem to be interchangeable but express very different ideas.  It seems I'm required to include a license when uploading to the app store, so if I'm excluding it here in order to get the app to compile, where do I include it later on when I'm ready to upload?  I hope someone can shed some more light on what's going on here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had to add the following lines to `packagingOptions {}`

```
exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
```

My problem was pretty foolish; when including `exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'` I got an error that *looked* very similar to the first one, but was in fact different.  adding `exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'` finally got everything working.  Still not sure why exactly I have to take these steps though.

Comment: No problem!  I'm comforted by the fact that so many other people have encountered this trivial problem as well :P

Comment: Facing same issue. when adding `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`. Do you know why `commons-io` and `org.apache.commons` are both included?? They seem to be the same stuff.

Comment: If I recall I remember really thinking they were the same thing coming from two different libraries. I never found out why this happened.

Comment: My guess is org.apache.commons:commons-io was renamed to commons-io:commons-io and org.apache.commons:commons-io now acts as a "symbolic link". There's nothing inside it but it has a dependency on commons-io:commons-io which holds the actual code.