# Android Studio : during application run i m getting error saying duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties

Tags: android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\sagar\AndroidStudioProjects\PrjectEmotin\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.microsoft.projectoxford\emotion\1.0.0\jars\libs\commons-io-2.4.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\sagar\AndroidStudioProjects\PrjectEmotin\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.microsoft.projectoxford\vision\1.0.354\jars\libs\commons-io-2.4.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Files copied in APK META-INF when Gradle building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815891/duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-when-gradle-building)

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution.Add the following piece of code in build.gradle file

android {
    packagingOptions {

```
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
}
```

}