# Import project from eclipse to android studio getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am new to Android Studio, I just import a project in Android Studio which was run in Eclipse. Few of error are resolved but this is not solved yet.

Here is error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File1: /home/user86/Downloads/IAH/app/libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar
>       File2: /home/user86/Downloads/IAH/app/libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar
>       File3: /home/user86/Downloads/IAH/app/libs/httpcore-4.2.2.jar

And here is build.gradle file code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packagename"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

Help to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Updated gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/volley.jar')}



android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.instantassignmenthelp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}}


packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'}
```

Comment: Try this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt

Comment: Did same, but not working.

Comment: can u post ur modified gradle file?

Comment: comment `compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673625/android-gradle-plugin-0-7-0-duplicate-files-during-packaging-of-apk

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - not working.

Comment: use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`

Comment: after build types you have closed 3 braces can you remove 1 and add that at last after packagingOptions?

Comment: Try to remove the jar dependencies and use a maven dependencies

Comment: ok, Thanks @Raghavendra

Comment: Is that worked @CoreAnd?

Comment: Yes, it works, packagingOptions must comes inside android tag.

Comment: @CoreAnd ok.. can I post that as answer will u accept it it might help others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packageOptions should come inside android tag.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.instantassignmenthelp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}




 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Problem for your **packagingOptions** Tag

**Advice**

Avoid calling `+`.

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' // Or latest stable version
```

**Finally**

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}


packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way , may solve your issue

if you are using `compile files('libs/volley.jar')` than you dont need following

Try removing

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
```