# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt. PackagingOptions doesnt helps

Tags: android, build.gradle

Although I have read similar questions and tried to apply this code :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude  'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

in my app build.gradle I still get the same error.

The error message in logcat:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':kalturaClient:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File1: /home/teo/Documents/AndroidStudioWorkspace/Kaltura/DemoApplication/kalturaClient/libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar
    File2: /home/teo/Documents/AndroidStudioWorkspace/Kaltura/DemoApplication/kalturaClient/libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
```

I have also tried to clean project but with no luck.
I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1

My build.gradle file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kaltura.activity"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}

}

dependencies {
compile project(':kalturaClient')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile files('libs/WidevineDRM-Debug-5.0.0.12188.jar')
compile files('libs/apksigtool.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/simple-social-sharing-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.2.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya file posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt

Comment: `packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }`

Comment: This one works! Thanks @IntelliJAmiya :)

Comment: i give same answer already @mt0s

Comment: @mt0s Move ahead .Happy coding

Comment: @RushDroid you are right - I just saw and used the comment first.

Comment: ok not an issue @mt0s :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add

```
android {
    // Fixed build error : Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

More details You may visit **[Android Studio 0.4 Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt)**

Answer (score 1):

try with this.

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
```

Hope it will help you.