# Get text from a webpage to string

Tags: android

I'm trying to get all the text to a String from a HTML document.

Here's my code

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Admissions extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView openclose;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admissions);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Text URL
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{"http://192.168.1.89/open_close.html"});

    openclose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.open_close);

}

public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null){
            openclose.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
        } else {
            openclose.setText("Error");
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}

}
```

Here's my message when 'BUILD'.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
>       File1: M:\AYUSH\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.4.jar
>       File2: M:\AYUSH\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.2.jar

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you code looks fine for this part, as far i understand issue is related to build. will you double check if is there any gradle related issue.

[you can also take help from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt)