# Errors building .apk with easywsdl generated code and ksoap2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ksoap2, easywsdl

I am getting the following error when trying to build an .apk on to a phone using android studio:

```
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.google.code.ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/pom.properties
    File1: /home/me/project/android-proj/app/libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
    File2: /home/me/project/android-proj/app/libs/easywsdl/ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar
```

The context is that I am using a bunch of easywsdl autogenerated code for communication with a web service. I just made some mods to the web service so had to regenerate the easywsdl code. This seemed to pull in a new dependency, ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar whereas previously it was ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I have been into the build.gradle file and commented out the dependency on the prev .jar file i.e.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    // compile files('libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/easywsdl/ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

UPDATE

reading the error msg a bit more carefully and thinking about it a little, I looked into the .jar files and noticed the following file:

```
META-INF/maven/com.google.code.ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/pom.properties
```

is present in both

```
 ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and

```
 ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar
```

and the contents of that file are identical in both instances

I also noticed that `META-INF/maven/com.google.code.ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/pom.properties` was also present in `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` (the previous .jar file used when everything was working) so my thinking is that `ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar` has changed and now erroneously includes a duplicate of this file

If I can remove this file from `ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar` then maybe it will fix the issue. No idea how to do that yet though..

UPDATE 2

This has now been fixed by the following mod to the `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    // compile files('libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/easywsdl/ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar')
    // compile files('libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

i.e. comment out all ksoap related dependencies other than `ExKsoap2-1.0.1.6.jar`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt

Comment: I don't think it is..

Comment: it definitely isn't a duplicate of this - problem is that android studio should automagically remove duplicate files in .jar dependencies but for some reason it isn't doing that for me anymore - hopefully I can figure out why..

Comment: see this link for further detail - http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: now fixed - see update 2