# android sdk app unfortunately stopped

Tags: android-support-library

.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field colorBackgroundFloating

this is my gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
apply(plugin: 'com.android.application')


repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kdu.routeP.app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'

        // Crappy workaround to gradle build error when running instrumentation tests
        // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'


    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:1.2.3'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

}
```

sometimes I change the support library to 23.1.1 it works,but when it comes to the tabbed view it not working, and when I checked the external libraries it has the support 25.0.0

Comment: i did replace all the occurances of 23 with 25,then it works,,