# Android Gradle Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/license.txt

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio-2.2

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE   File1: C:\Users\hdeka.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.

Comment: Have you tried this link, should be the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can add a few lines of code, in your app gradle file, to get rid of that error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YourAppId"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
    // these are the lines that you have to add
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    //include below line if you are using firebase
    //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Let me know if it works. :-)