# 2 files found with path 'META-INF/LGPL2.11'

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-jetifier

Does anybody knows how to debug this? I cannot figure out which libraries are generating the problem.

Side note, it only happens when I try to run Android tests so my best guess is it's related to some testing library.

```
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$version_room"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
    // Compose Tests
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$version_compose"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$version_compose"
    // Hilt test
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$version_hilt"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$version_hilt"
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.6'
```

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/LGPL2.1' from inputs:
      - /home/lbenevento/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1e2dfa6057fe4e701d175f47b1099efa/transformed/jetified-jna-platform-5.5.0.jar
      - /home/lbenevento/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/405542266c1c406c39ff1a20cb26a332/transformed/jetified-jna-5.5.0.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
     for more information

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
...
```

This is the full error: https://pastebin.com/74cLGMR9

Comment: This was happening to me, too, when I added `androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$version_compose"`

Comment: Okay, that's good to know, so we should probably exclude some sub-dependency of that dependency.

Answer (score 33):

This happened for me when I added `androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$version_compose"`.

Referring to the advice in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682960/1229936), I decided to use [`pickFirst`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#pickfirsts) as opposed to [`exclude`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#excludes).

According to the [PackagingOptions documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions), [`pickFirst`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#pickfirsts) will allow for the first occurrence of the file to be packaged with the APK, whereas [`exclude`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#excludes) would exclude all occurrences of the file.

This ended up working for me:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work for me too indeed. But I'm still not getting what exactly is the problem and how could we know what dependencies are causing it, do you have any more insights?

Comment: work for me! marked the answer

Answer (score 10):

So the `exclude` and `pickFirst` already deprecated in kotlin DSL. put the following in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
android {   
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.apply {
            add("META-INF/LICENSE")
            add("META-INF/*.properties")
            add("META-INF/AL2.0")
            add("META-INF/LGPL2.1")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the kotlin DSL has resources.pickFirsts

Comment: resources.pickFirsts is the alternative method. should we use excludes or pickFirst?

Comment: @neo It doesn't matter. Just use those as works properly.

Answer (score 5):

This worked out for a similar issue for me:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this solution but what does it means? I guess we are excluding some paths from those who get bundled into the APK, but how can we know there isn't something we need in there? Do you have any more info? Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hey Lorenzo hi, sadly I don't have more information about this, haven't looked into it. The LICENSE file seems important...

Comment: the kotlin DSL has resources.pickFirsts. should we use excludes or pickFirst?

Answer (score 1):

I was tried to setup kotlin into my java project and fixed the above issue by adding this into build.gradle

```
android{
        packagingOptions {
                    resources {
                        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work to others

```
    packaging.resources {
        pickFirsts += "/META-INF/LICENSE.md"
        pickFirsts += "/META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md"
        pickFirsts += "/META-INF/AL2.0"
        pickFirsts += "/META-INF/LGPL2.1"
    }
```

But in the end I end up having more problems.

I suggest if you have a interface to the class that your mocking. Just create a fake class and inherit the interface and just return what will you do in mock, it's just the same

For example

```
interface SomeRepository {
fun getDetails(): SomeModel
fun getApiCall(): Resource<String>
}
```

Create a fake class

```
class FakeSomeRepository : SomeRepository {
override fun getDetails(): SomeModel {
return SomeModel() //add model properties here

override fun getApiCall(): Resource<String> {
//create different logic here to return Success, Loading, Error
return Resource.Success("Returned String")
}
```

And in your test class

```
class SomeViewModelTest {

private lateinit var someViewModel: SomeViewModel
private lateinit var fakeRepository = FakeSomeRepository()

@Before
fun setup() {
someViewModel = SomeViewModel(fakeRepository)
}

@Test
fun `some test`() = runTest {
assertThat.(someViewModel.getDetails()).isEqualTo(SomeModel())
}
}
```

it's just a snippet, but I hope it would help anyone who read this. You can also see articles in medium that supports using fakes than mocking.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
  packagingOptions {
        resources {
            resources.excludes.add("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE.md")
            resources.excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md")
        }
    }
```

Comment: the kotlin DSL has resources.pickFirsts. should we use excludes or pickFirst?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete jetified-jna-5.5.0.jar or jetified-jna-platform-5.5.0.jar. One cache import is not necessary.