# Android Studio - Error Building - Android tasks have already been created

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Getting the following error when building the project:

Error:(2, 0) Android tasks have already been created.
This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
continue configuring the model.

Root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
      }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
       versionCode 5
       versionName '5'
       targetSdkVersion 19
       minSdkVersion 10
       applicationId 'tsp.movil'
    }
}
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
     buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tsp.movil"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 5
        versionName '5'
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.txt'
         }
     }
     productFlavors {
     }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Top Level **build.gradle** file should only have the configuration common for all modules of your project.

make the following changes :

Root **build.gradle** file should have only this piece of code

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
      }
}

allprojects{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
      }
}
```

Comment: Works just fine, but allprojects should be in lower case.

Comment: ya, :( No suggestion on stackoverflow editor, BDW  updated the answer .

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue, with the same error message. The issue in my case was that I've had created a module inside a package and then deleted it manually in (MacOS) Finder.

The problem was that I forgot to also remove the `include ::myModule` line from the `settings.gradle` file.

Answer (score -1):

look on this:
[How to define common android properties for all modules using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404476/how-to-define-common-android-properties-for-all-modules-using-gradle)
the 3rd comment says Android tasks have already been created. This happens when calling android.applicationVariants, android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants. Once these methods are called, it is not possible to continue configuring the model.