# How to change build tools version in Android Studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android-studio, configuration, build-tools

I just upgraded my Android studio from 2.3 to 3.0.1. But I get this error message(I have already installed API 27 ) and don't know how to fix it, because I couldn't find the the build tools version in new version of android studio!

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2 <a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project</a>
```

The gradle files are changed, also the project structure has only one tab!

Edit:
    this is the content of `app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.m.finalocr"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

As you can see, there is no `buildToolsVersion` in it. So, why my android studio looks for this specific version(26) of that when I have the 27 version installed on my computer? Also, where can I see the `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" and change it to`buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" ` ?

Comment: If a specific version isn't specified, the latest one installed will be used by default.

Comment: As the OP I too have found this NOT to be the case. It just asks for an older version without it being specified ANYWHERE in the project. The accepted answer does not tell us WHY it's looking for that specific version.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your project is looking for Build Tools version 26.0.2, but you haven't yet downloaded and installed it on your computer.

To download it, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager, then click on the "SDK Tools" tab at the top of the new window. Then select the "Show Package Details" checkbox in the lower right-hand corner. Finally, scroll down to where you see 26.0.2, check the checkbox next to it, and click "OK" to begin the install process.

If you want to change the Build Tools version in your project, that is specified in project's build.gradle file (in the 'app' module). Open the file and either add or update the Build Tools version you want to use by adding/updating the following property in the 'android' section:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where can I change the version? May you explain more ?
In android studio 2.3 it was inside build.gradle(app) in the Android tree

Comment: @user3486308 I edited the answer to include information on how to update the version; hopefully that answers your question - you are correct, it is in the build.grade file in the app module.

Comment: @user3486308 In that case, you need to ADD the line: buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" in the android section of your build.gradle file. Look at the sample code in my answer, and add that to the android section of your code. I'm not sure why it is defaulting the way that it is, but as long as you specific the exact version you want, it should work for you.

Comment: @shagberg What version of the build tools will be used by default if I don't specify it?

Comment: @karl That is a good question... according to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools, "If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies." By default, the plugin uses the minimum version of the build tools required by the version of the plugin you're using.

Comment: @shagberg Thanks for the info. I see why they did that, and that it makes it useful for starting out, but it makes it a little annoying when you want more control

Comment: @shagberg I'm back with a new question - do you know if it's possible to set this for *all* modules at once? Or do I have to add this block to every single module?

Comment: @karl Not sure what you mean by "all modules"... the buildToolsVersion is set once per application in the build.gradle file, so I don't understand what you mean by "all modules".

Comment: @shagberg I have an application with multiple modules. I want to be able to set this once and not have to worry about remembering to specify the buildToolsVersion when I add a new module. I ended up using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30677615/1139908

Comment: `buildToolsVersion` property is no longer needed starting from gradle v3.0.0

Comment: `buildToolsVersion` property is no longer needed starting from gradle v3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

**"Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S"** also redirects you to android studio's **"Project structure"** which gives you the option to change Build tools version.