# npx react-native run-android does not work - "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Just recently ejected expo and I'm trying to run my app on an android device. I followed the instructions (hopefuly right) but I keep getting this error when I try to run my app:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\User\Documents\jad for eject\jad\jad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue on Windows, and my problem was with the Gradle `local.properties` file.
It contained the following:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
sdk.dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

The problem was probably the windows backslash (`\`). What worked is escaping it:

```
org.gradle.java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-15.0.1"
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this issue for 3 hours but nothing worked.

I managed to solve my issue by removing the quote in the **local.properties** file :

```
sdk.dir = "C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk"
```

To

```
sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve the issue by changing

```
sdk.dir =   C:\Users\mob\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

to

```
sdk.dir =   C:\\Users\\mob\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks @Pratik nice and easy fix

Answer (score 1):

I Solved the issues by below setting:

Adding the following commands at end in my `android > gradlew` script:

```
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"

yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

And Under `android > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties` change

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.{any}-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

And also check node version if `node v12` or above then update `JDK v{any}` to `JDK v14`.

Also in `android > build.gradle` change

> `buildToolsVersion: {any}` to `buildToolsVersion: 28.0.3`

And before changing buildToolsVersion check whether you have installed `v28.0.3` or not. If not then no problem the above two commands install it automatically.

and the last thing is to check whether you have the `local.properties` file or not. If it is present under `android` folder then check your sdk path is correct. And if it is not present then under `android` folder create a new file named `local.properties` and under that file write the following command:

> sdk.dir=`Your SDK folder path`

Hopefully, after the following setting you are good to go to run `npx react-native run-android`

This Worked for me!

Comment: you can post new SO for this. Perhaps creating new SO can resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issues on my react native project but i fix then using the following steps on windows users:

1. Delete your **node_modulues** and  reinstall it
2. check or increase your grade distributionUrl  to **6.+**
3. create or your **local.properties** to match this `sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`
4. add the following under your **gradew**

> yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
>
> yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, understand that the `JavaIOException` occurs when the java could not file the directory or any file it is looking for. So, in your case the `gradlew` is looking for the **SDK** and it is not finding it.

To resolve this issue, check `build.gradle` for this:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
}
```

As, you see the `buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"`. This name should be under your `$SDK_DIR/build-tools/` by the folder named `28.0.3`. If your `buildToolsVersion` and the name of the folder is mismatched it throws `JavaIOException`. So, change the `buildToolsVersion` as you require from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137176).

*If this does not work, try restarting your PC.*

Answer (score 0):

Ive just remove both of these lines from gradle **local.properties**

```
org.gradle.java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19"
sdk.dir = "D:\\Android_SDK"
```

and then added this enviroment variable to my system :

**ANDROID_SDK_ROOT -> "Path of my installed SDK"**. like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I managed to solve my issue by adding the double slashes in the local.properties file :

```
From This:  sdk.dir=C:\Users\Ashi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

To This :   sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\Ashi\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

For me this Worked Successfully.