# What went wrong: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: react-native

I just started learning react-native a couple days ago, and I got a bug during installation and setting up. The moment I run the cmd "npx react-native run-android", and I got this error.

Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
  to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.''

Please help me guys. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx react-native run-android does not work - "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263528/npx-react-native-run-android-does-not-work-java-io-ioexception-the-filename)

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue with the incorrect SDK location. Can you verify if there is a local.properties in your android folder under your React Native project with right sdk location path in it

Also verify the below code in gradle-wrapper.properties present in gradle/wrapper folder

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3- 
all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```