# Mapping new ns to old ns

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to 4.2.1 and delete jcentor.I had a warning like this when build the project.I don't understand the means of these URL and how to fix it

Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01

Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem when importing an old project, then updating my dependencies.
I solved it by updating my buildToolsVersion from 30.0.2 to 30.0.3
Know that this is old, but maybe it will save someone a little headache.

Comment: Your answer led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137176/12039062) about how to do what you say.

Comment: this answer solve my same problem. I think the asker should make it as answer