# In Android Studio Giving Warning of Mapping New ns to old ns

Tags: android, android-studio

When I trying to run the app or Rebuid it, Gives following errors.

(I m trying run or Rebuild old project in new Android Studio and SDK)

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http:/ /schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http:/ /schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http:/ /schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http:/ /schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http:/ /schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

My Build Gradle is Like following;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.etas.etas"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ksoap.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.2'
}
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping new ns to old ns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645844/mapping-new-ns-to-old-ns)

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading your Gradle plugin to the latest one.

1. Go to `path/to/your/flutter_app/android/build.gradle` and inside the
   dependencies block in `buildscript` you have to update your old
   build Gradle to the latest one.
2. Also update Gradle distributionUrl in `path/to/your/flutter_app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to the same version you updated to
3. Clean your flutter project using `flutter clean`
4. Run your project again

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and reinstalling the SDK platforms.

Delete the folders in

if you are Linux user:

```
 ~/Android/Sdk/platforms
```

if you are Windows user:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

and download the SDKs you need.

Comment: I m windows user. I deleted and installed the SDK Platform. But result is same. The problem did not solved.

Comment: More info : I m trying run or Rebuild old project in new Android Studio and SDK